# Codesandbox gives "Target container is not a DOM element" error for React app, but webpack-dev-server does not

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

I am attempting to take my git repo with a practice React app and put it into codesandbox.io so that I can show it to others I am working with more easily. I followed the instructions at got my sandbox up here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/cdpautsch/react-learning-area/tree/master/test-app2

However, I get the error: `Target container is not a DOM element`

```
evaluate
/src/index.js:52:9
  49 |     }
  50 | }
  51 | 
> 52 | ReactDOM.render((
     |         ^
  53 |     <Provider store={store}>
  54 |         <BrowserRouter>
  55 |             <div>
```

This error does NOT come up on my machine when I am running with webpack-dev-server.

My code from `index.js`:

```js
ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Navbar />

                <Route exact path = "/" component = {Home} />
                <Route path = "/cards" component = {CardsGame} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

My code from `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>TestApp2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It says it's not a valid element, but it's definitely there and definitely has the right name. What am I missing?

Updating with additional information:
* The app was not created with `create-react-app`, but initialized and loaded with packages manually
* Sandbox seems to default to CRA, and this may affect how it runs?

Comment: This is awfully strange, but I just changed the name of the div to 'root' and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Did you use CRA for this?  The index.html file is never being rendered on the sandbox since index.js is never linked in the file.  Create-react-app does some wonky behind the scenes building to insert all the scripts into the HTML file when the app is built, but if you're just copy/pasting the content that link will not translate.

Comment: I don't recall if I did it all from scratch, or created it with CRA then deleted everything to do it from scratch, but it's not supposed to use CRA. I noticed that in the template but don't know how to turn it off. I wanted full control over how it's setup, so that's why I didn't want to use CRA.

Comment: Ejecting a CRA app usually just leads to a big headache in my experience, but I'm no expert. If you're just interested in getting it to work on codesandbox, all you have to do is stick in a script tag to link the HTML and JS files: ```<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"/>```

Comment: Well I didn't eject it. If it _used_ to be CRA, then I would've deleted everything in the directory. `package.json` only has the stuff that I put in. There shouldn't be anything left behind.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to change the strange build functionality it has requires ejecting it, I believe anyway.

Comment: But none of that is left, if it was there to begin with. I'm actually thinking that I didn't use CRA at all (working on a lot of stuff lately so I get mixed up), and I'm 90% sure I created this just with npm init and then installed my own packages manually. So CRA shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193654/discussion-between-rutherford-wonkington-and-cdpautsch).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old issue, however for anyone coming here late to the game like myself. Try moving the `index.html` file into the `src` directory. This is an issue with 'codesandbox'. I did this and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also try to move index.html out of src if it's in src.
I did it and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution can be to use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementById('app')`. This would also work fine in codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that for me this bug actually happens when using document.getElementById of any kind.

It probably has something to do with the way Codesandbox interprets the JavaScript, but in my case, I had this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {createPortal(<p>Portal Div</p>, document.getElementById("portal"))}
      <div id="portal"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For this code, I would get the same error you have

If I change: `document.getElementById("portal")` with `document.body` temporarily, save the file, allow react to rerender, and then change back to `document.getElementById("portal")` the code would work again (at least temporarily)